# How to fix sed command on MacOS with error extra characters after \ at the end of c command?

Tags: macos, sed

Following sed command works on Linux and Windows but fails on MacOS/BSD:

```
sed -i '/"appId"/c\  \"appId":\  \"'${applicationId}'\",' $capacitorConfigJson
```

I tried to add ' ' -e

```
sed -i ' ' -e '/"appId"/c\  \"appId":\  \"'${applicationId}'\",' $capacitorConfigJson
```

and then script fail with error:

```
sed: 1: "/"appId"/c\  \"appId":\ ...": extra characters after \ at the end of c command
```

I found similar solutions to add newline after c\ but it doesn't seems to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this on BSD (OSX) `sed`:

```
sed -i.bak '/"appId"/c\ 
"appId": "'${applicationId}'",
' "$capacitorConfigJson"
```

Note that there is a space after `c\`